# How to fetch a form data and to insert the data into another form in the exact field using PHP or any other

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

here I have form 1 and from 2 with same fields and if I click a button form 2 should open with the fetched data from form 1.
The fetched data from Form 1 should exactly placed into form 2. (bcoz both forms has same fields)  any help would be appreciated.

**> Code for Form 1**

```
<table class="auto-style15" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
<tr>
    <td class="auto-style21" style="width: 44px"><strong>Sl No</strong></td>
    <td class="auto-style21" style="width: 115px"><strong>Part No</strong></td>
    <td class="auto-style21" style="width: 88px"><strong>Part Rev</strong></td>
</tr>
<td class="auto-style7" style="width: 44px">
    <input name="Text157" style="width: 35px" type="text" /></td>
    <td class="auto-style7" style="width: 115px">
    <input name="Text20" style="width: 75px" type="text" /></td>
    <td class="auto-style7" style="width: 88px">
    <input name="Text232" style="width: 75px" type="text" /></td>
</td>
</table>
```

> *button*

```
<input id="cmaudit1" style="width: 90px" type="submit" value="Audit Checklist" 
    onClick="window.open ('form/CM form2.php',' width=500,height=400')"/>
```

> **Code for form 2** where the datas from form 1 should fetch and display into the exact fields of form 2 , when a button is clicked

```
<table class="auto-style15" style="width: 100%; height: 50%">
    <input name="Text134" style="width: 130px; height: 38px;" type="text" /></td>
    <td class="auto-style21" style="width: 98px"><strong>Part</strong>
    <strong>NO</strong></td>
    <td class="auto-style7" style="width: 113px">

    <input name="Text129" style="width: 130px; height: 38px;" type="text" /></td>
    <td class="auto-style21" style="width: 59px"><strong>Rev</strong>
    <strong>No</strong></td>
    <td class="auto-style7" style="width: 101px">

    <input name="Text130" style="width: 130px; height: 38px;" type="text" />    </td>
    <td class="auto-style21" style="width: 60px"><strong>PO</strong> <strong>
    No</strong></td>
    <td class="auto-style7" style="width: 117px">
</td>
</table>
```

Comment: I see no form fields in "form 2".

Comment: actually I have the fields same as the form 1

Answer (score 0):

You can set the first form's method to POST or GET, and then just set the values for the other form's fields to the older field names.

```
<input type="text" name="fieldname_form_2" value="<?php echo $_POST['fieldname_form_1'] ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a form that's "multiple steps"? There are a few solutions that may help if so...

1: Save the previous posted data in a session or cookie. Use this data later. Sessions would be more of an ideal solution.

Form 1:

```
<form method="post" action="step2.php">
  <input type="text" name="your_name" placeholder="Your name">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Form 2 (step2.php):

```
<?php $_SESSION['postData'] = $_POST; /* super simple example */ ?>
<form method="post" action="step3.php">
  <input type="text" name="your_address" placeholder="Your address">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Form 3 (step3.php):

```
<?php $_SESSION['postData'] = array_merge($_SESSION['postData'], $_POST); /* super simple example */ ?>
<form method="post" action="finished.php">
  <input type="text" name="your_address" placeholder="Your address">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then you can use `$_SESSION['postData']` later.

---

2: Echo the posted data into hidden input fields. Example:

Form 1:

```
<form method="post" action="step2.php">
  <input type="text" name="your_name" placeholder="Your name">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Form 2 (step2.php):

```
<form method="post" action="step3.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="your_name" value="<?php echo htmlentities($_POST['your_name']) ?>">
  <input type="text" name="your_address" placeholder="Your address">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

... etc ... (note, these forms are not comprehensive and have not been tested. To be used as example only.)

Comment: I dont have multiple forms I have form 1 and form 2 with the same fields. the data entered in the form 1 should display in the form 2. in the exact fields of form 2. thanks ofr ur ans.. :)

Comment: Are both forms on the same page? You contradict yourself when you say `I dont have multiple forms I have form 1 and form 2 with the same fields.`

Comment: no I have a it in two different page, I thought u mean it for 3 forms.. 
I have two different forms separately...

Comment: As I said in my answer, it's for an example. The answer you're probably looking for lies within my answer ;)

Comment: hello thanks for the code, but I couldn't get the action ="step3.php" or "step2.php" , it would be better if you use the exact example which I had mentioned

Answer (score 0):

too many mistakes and a simple question come out. Where are form tag in form2 code?
Maybe you just want to fill the table with the value of

```
<input name="Text157" style="width: 35px" type="text" />
<input name="Text20" style="width: 75px" type="text" />
<input name="Text232" style="width: 75px" type="text" />
```

in the correct cell of the second table.
In this case you need to use a javascript/jQuery function that write html contents inside the table, with the onclick event of the button(where is the button?)

Too few code for a better response

Comment: hello, may be you can check now and give your best solution.. thanks in advance...

Comment: Still too few information. Do not be angry with me, but where is the part of PHP? How do you pass the values​​? GET or POST? Based on what fill in the various tags with the variables used, something like <input type = "text" value = "<? Php echo $ _POST ['Text157']?>" /> as told by the other answer

Comment: I'm also not sure that the event onclick="window.open(.....)" going to submit the form and pass the correct values to form2.php

Comment: hello, I dont know how to do, so tats y I asked in this forum..if I know most of the part already then I might do it myself.. ;) ..if there is any wrong or error, it would be great if you rectify it..or ignore it. But as far as now when I click a button form 2 opens

Comment: and its little bit messy if I submit the whole code of the form tats y posted the table. alone..

Comment: Ok, well, if the posted code it's all of your code i don't know how help you, or better, maybe your knowledge of html/php/jquery must be reevaluated

Comment: ah okay gut, I had used Microsoft webexpression, maybe I should write a feedback and ask them re-valuate the software and I wondered that how could others findout and give their answers...anyways thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use $_POST to fetch values from form 1:
*index.php*

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Index 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="index2.php" method="post">
            Part No<input type="text" name="PartNo" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Send">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

*index2.php*

```
<?php 
 $partNo=0;
if(!empty($_POST))
{
    $partNo=$_POST['PartNo'];
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Index 2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="index2.php" method="post">
            Part No : <?php echo $partNo; ?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```